# Find all paths from root to leaf in a TreeView

Tags: c#, xml, treeview

I'm using the method described on this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317597), to display XML File in TreeView control.

But I need to get all paths from root to the leaves 
How to get it ?

Please please help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your referenced page answers your question and describes completely how to get all the paths from root to leaves. This is steps 1 through to 8.